# Publishing .NET Core Web App to Linux on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to publish my .Net Core 2.2 Web app to a Linux environment.

I already created the Web App with a ServicePlan with Linux. I downloaded the publish profile and published it successfully.

I published it over FTP profile.

[image]

The problem is that when I access the web app address, it still shows the Azure Empty State web app:

[image]

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: It's been a long time since I messed with this, but I seem to call Azure drops like an index.html file in the root of a new Azure site. Perhaps you need to remove that file? When you publish, is there an option to remove existing files?

Comment: @mason Yes, there's an option to do that. I will try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @mason Just checked the option and the behavior continues. Do you have any more ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to repro your scenario and could see the same behavior.

There is a way one can [configure Default documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json#configure-default-documents) for App Services, however, this is valid only for App Services on **Windows** and not **Linux**.

For Linux apps, the implementation would be based as per the runtime stack selected.

For .Net Core Razor pages specifically, the `AddPageRoute()` method can help in defining the route as described in [this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-a-custom-default-page-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) blog post:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        //"/Home/welcome" is the page we want to land at
        //The empty string signifies the root URL   

        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/welcome", "");
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

That said, this worked only when published locally but not when published to the Azure App Service for Linux, which is not what one would expect.

I will check this with our internal Teams and get back to you. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

**UPDATE:**

You could configure the Startup Command for your App Service. For .Net Core, it would look something like `dotnet <myapp>.dll`. This should definitely work. You can configure this setting here:

[image: Startup Command Configuration]

Note that you might have to delete all existing files prior to publish (from your Publish profile > Settings > File Publish Options > enable "Delete all existing files prior to publish" > Save) to see your changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @Bhargavi, thank you very much for your answer and helpfulness on this. It would be really important for me to get this working!

Comment: Hey Perozzo, I see that this works now without any issues, i.e., I see the landing page that I configured instead of the default one provided by Azure. Could you please give it another try and check what happens?

Comment: However, if you still see issues, you could configure the [Startup Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#built-in-images) for your App Service. For .Net Core, it would look something like `dotnet <myapp>.dll`. This should definitely work. Note that you might have to delete all existing files prior to publish to see your changes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Updated my answer above to include the Startup Command workaround.

Comment: @perozzo Just running a quick check to see if you're still blocked?

Comment: Hello! Just tried again and still not working. I'm using FTP publish because via Web Deploy I'm getting an error. At the time I made this question, the Web Deploy option wasn't working as well.

Comment: About the Startup Command, where exactly do I have to go to configure it?

Comment: Hey! Just checking if you have any updates about my last comment! Thank you!

Comment: Hey there @perozzo. Added a screenshot to help find the setting. Please try it out and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hello! Perfect. Just added the command and I think that problem was resolved. But now, the azure empty state page is gone and the browser is returning "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". Just checked some websites and this problem seems related to https redirection. It was enabled in my web app. I disabled it but the problem continues. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @perozzo Does restarting your app service help?

Comment: @perozzo Have you had a chance to check?

Comment: Hello Bhargavi. I'll test it today.

Comment: Sure, I've my fingers crossed! ;)

Comment: @perozzo Long time! Any luck here?

Comment: Hello Bhargavi, so sorry for making you waiting. Had some problems here, but now I'm back. I'm trying again to publish to Linux. As soon as I finish, I let you know.

Comment: Bhargavi, the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in the browser still occurs. I tried private browsing, restarted app service and the problem continues. Maybe I'm creating the web app in the wrong way?

Comment: Just got it working using .netcore 3.1. With < 3.1, no way to get it working. I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@bharatdwarkani/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-3-0-app-in-azure-linux-app-service-explained-from-scratch-6e45392ca256